# Is it possible to use high level Azure Policy Allowed Resources types?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am attempting to create a policy to lock down resource groups and would like to just use a list of high level resource types instead of trying to granularly assign types as there are hundreds. is this possible? Using a powershell script I pulled the list of types and was trying to just use top level ones such as:

```
["Microsoft.KeyVault","Microsoft.AzureData","Microsoft.Billing","Microsoft.Cache","Microsoft.Consumption","Microsoft.ContainerInstance","Microsoft.ContainerRegistry","Microsoft.ContainerService","Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL","Microsoft.DevOps","Microsoft.MachineLearning","Microsoft.ServiceBus","Microsoft.Sql","Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine","Microsoft.Storage","Microsoft.Web"]
```

but it didn't validate it. Is there a possibility of a syntax error in my array, am I doing something else wrong, or is it just straight up not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "notContains" to check the resource type:

```
{
  "field": "type",
  "notContains": "Microsoft.KeyVault"
}
```